# How do I scrape the info from a table on a webpage when the info is created dynamically by javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the info from the table on this page: http://www.dectech.co.uk/football/index.php

I'm a html, css, javascript noob and was wondering how I can get the actual info rather than the html.

I'll use the info in an android app I'm developing (so using java).

Sorry if this seems a bit vague but I know very little about how javascript is run on webpages.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's ur data in JSON format :[http://www.dectech.co.uk/cgi-bin/new_site/GetUpcomingGames.pl?divID=](http://www.dectech.co.uk/cgi-bin/new_site/GetUpcomingGames.pl?divID=0)0

use any standard parser to get the data from this :)

Comment: Ah lovely! Is there an API for dectech as I'd also like to get games from the Championship and Leagues 1 & 2?

Comment: **Edit:** I see you just change the div id in the url to get different leagues. Many thanks Sajjan

Comment: Is it a recent addition or has there always been a json feed?

Comment: I have no idea at all! Ive never seen the website before  I just inspected it using Chrome..:)

Comment: ah sorry, your knowledge of the site led me to assume that you worked on it!